# Android Studio switching from design view to code view

Tags: android-studio

Is there a way, when working on a layout (xml) to switch from a design view to the code view with focus on the selected element, such as double clicking in the eclipse ADT?
Thanks

Comment: I'm also missing the same bro and now I hate Android Studio more than I used to love Eclipse-Adt

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can go from design view to xml select item and then Right click on item  then select option => **Go to Declaration**(Function key + F3 in window ).

1.You can use "**PREVIEW"** (Right side on android studio). when working on xml in android studio. it will help you :) a side window appear with design view

Comment: That I know. I wanted to know if there is an option to define to go there from the design view

Comment: @Manishrajpurohit Whatever you posted is supposed to be a comment, not an answer!

Comment: thanks Delhi-Boy for the tip...at least something there... hence upvote

Comment: @ShirishHerwade :)

Answer (score 0):

No, You can check design view from code using preview but can not go to code from design view.